# Is Interfacing both java.awt.Graphics2D and Html5 Canvas Context in GWT feasible?

Tags: html, gwt, canvas, awt, graphics2d

I have a java library which heavily uses java.awt.Graphics2d.

I want to port my library to html5 canvas by using gwt.

So I'm planning to write an interface (or just a class), say common.Graphics2d, 
an adapter class, say com.test.awt.Graphics2d, implements common.Graphics2d and uses java.awt.Graphics2d

and another adapter class, say com.test.gwt.Graphics2d, implements common.Graphics2d and uses com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d.

Then I will replace all java.awt.Graphics2d with common.Graphics2d.
So after that, my library will work on both gwt and java.

The problem here is to implement graphics2d methods, and configuration by canvas context 2d. Is it feasible to implement same functionality with canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing. I have an interface which represents aview and two implementations of said interface. One for Android using its `android.graphics` classes and a second implementations in GWT using `com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas`.

The GWT canvas stuff seems pretty full-featured to me. You can draw shapes, display text and images, move, rotate, scale...

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the functions you use (for instance color gradient may not be easy). for basic drawing functions, the number of methods you really need to implement is very small.

You can have a look (and reuse) classes from my jvect-clipboard package for instance (on sourceforge). Basically, all geometric methods can use the general path drawing commmand, and you are left with storing colors and the like.

Have a look for instance at the implementation for SVG or WMF output, you will see that the code is pretty simple, especially for SVG (although it doesn't cover all possibilities, in particular gradients).